# How to protect against a worldwide EMP?

Tags: apocalypse, electromagnetism, protection

What are the ways to protect against EMP and can they be used to protect storage facilities, vehicles and indoor hydroponic farms ?

- The cause of the EMP is a meteorite crash around the same as what hit the dinosaurs.
- The temperature is going to go over 100°.
- The protections should be effective   against other disasters that would cause EMP to happen to justify the money if the the ways of protection are very costly (a giant meteor strike isn't something that happen often enough to dump public money that could be used elsewhere)

EMP isn't the most noticeable effect when tsunamis are destroying coastals cities and that the air at the surface is hot enough to kill people however once the ash create a volcanic winter having the means to feed, light and heat the shelter sound really important.

Comment: If you have an underground shelter wouldn't it likely be naturally protected from EMPs due to the amount of concrete or rock it has over it?

Comment: I definitely not a EMP expert so I guess that will do for the shelters but i'm unsure about the feasibility of big storage facilities/hydroponic farms though I don't really know about it, an answer about how thick the protective layers of concrete needs to be and how easy it is to store and take back the things inside would be quite useful.

Comment: I'd rather say that the EMP would be the first noticeable effect of such a hit! Sismic waves would take minutes to travel across the globe, same for the tsunami and the shock wave. The EMP, travelling at the speed of light, less than a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can protect your electronics from an EMP using a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Line the inner walls of your bunker with a fine mesh of conducting material on all sides and anything inside of it will be protected. The mesh must be finer than the wavelength of the EMP you want to defend against.

Comment: Faraday cage would have to be thick solid Sheets of metal rather than the traditional mesh due to the broad bandwidth and sheer energy of the EMP.

Answer (score 2):

With a meteor of that scale, the least of your worries will be the EMP. The energy of impact will instantly vaporize the meteor itself and an equivalent mass of the earth's crust. The shockwave will be felt around the world as major earthquakes.

Portions of the mantle may be exposed briefly,  a large mass of sulfur will be vaporized.  The heat of impact will cause fires across half the world. Molten rock fragments will rain from the sky around the world for days.

In short, I feel no amount of concrete can protect you from the simple mechanical damage.

Defense against EMP effects, in contrast, is simple. It  requires a solid metal casing around the electrical and electronic systems.